# Site uses two logos to link to a 'home' page; what's the best practice?

Tags: homepage

I have a very comprehensive and complex client website which is proving troublesome.

There is a main logo for the 'home' company page and within the top level navigation structure there is category (not a microsite) which due to it being a part of the umbrella company has the same logo - but with a strapline.

The client insists on using both logos, however wants both 'home' logos to link back to their respective 'home' pages.

I have included a 'home' button icon link within the navigation system as it requires it (not everyone using the site is web savvy).

1. I was just wondering has anyone come across this problem before?
2. Should I link the main company logo to the main 'home' page and the category logo to its 'home' page.

Just for info, the end user can always get back to the main company 'home' page by clicking on the 'home' button icon.

I look forward to your comments.

Cheers

Comment: You mean something like how the BBC website(s) work? http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/ They have a main logo that goes to the 'umberella' site and a logo of the current site section that takes you to the home page of that site area.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but it's more complex than that. The logos will actually 'swap' over when the end user clicks onto the 'Category B'homepage link.

The only difference between logos is the strapline on the 'Category B' homepage link.

Comment: seems you already have an answer in mind that you want to hear.  if you force people to confirm your conclusion by not allowing any other options then their agreement means very little

Comment: Just trying to give the problem some context. I am not sure what the 'right' answer is, which brings me to throwing the question out there. 

As mentioned previously the website is complex and I've not had this issue or seen this issue before. Any ideas are welcome - I definitely haven't got any preconceived ideas on this one.

Comment: Clarification: "Strapline" is UK English for "Tagline", correct? Like a slogan under the logo?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest adding the two logos as a separate navigation and the "home button" to take you to the home of the Company page you are in.

That way the user will identify that there are 2 different pages and each one has its unique navigation structure.

i.e.

[image: 2 pages]

[image: icons]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - however what makes this even more complicated is that the only difference between the logos is that 'Category B' has a strapline. The strapline does not give the end user any further clues - this will especially confusing to a new end user. I think introducing the logos side by side will further confuse the end user.

Happy to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: If your branding allows using logos in negative colours then you can grey out one logo and use the other in black. And if there is a text that would help identify the types it would be useful to add. I've added an image to explain.In this case I am using "corporate and personal", the logos almost the same but the shade of colour gives away the difference.

Comment: Thanks again Rosie - I wish the logos were different in colour, however the logos are exactly the same. The logo is a actually of real fruit (not my idea!) and the strapline separates them.

I think it just looks odd - when you click between the pages and one logo has a strapline and the other doesn't. To the none initiated it looks like a mistake.

Comment: I use something akin to this for co-branding all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If this sub-section of the website is very important and acts like a mini-site of its own, with its own sub-logo, then two logos can be linked to their own respective index pages.

- Main Logo - links to the Homepage of the website
- Secondary Logo - links to the index page of the mini-site

But if you do this, then "Home" links in the menu should also link to the respective index pages, otherwise it will be confusing for the users. **I suggest to have additional link in the mini-site navigation menu that points to the Homepage of the main website.** You can probably name it something like "Back to Main Page" etc.